# Checking if radio button is checked after submitting and page reloads in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I m stuck. I have radio buttons as such

```
<fieldset class="servicesInfoTable" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
<legend><span class="req">*</span>Select Service:</legend>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnServiceType" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Home</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Office/Retail</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

When page reloads after file submit i want to retain the radio button selected and show and hide from elements accordingly. This same code works fine with desktop site but its not firing up in Jquery Mobile.

I have tried the following

```
if ($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtnServiceType_0').prop("checked")) {
    $(".packageInfoTable").css('display', 'block');
    $(".tblServiceFrequency").css('display', 'None');
    $(".frequency").css('display', 'None');
    $(".hoursInfoTable").css('display', 'None');

}
```

Tried this too

```
if ($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtnServiceType_0').attr("checked")) {
    $(".packageInfoTable").css('display', 'block');
    $(".tblServiceFrequency").css('display', 'None');
    $(".frequency").css('display', 'None');
    $(".hoursInfoTable").css('display', 'None');

}
```

And this:

```
if ($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtnServiceType_0').is(":checked")) {
    $(".packageInfoTable").css('display', 'block');
    $(".tblServiceFrequency").css('display', 'None');
    $(".frequency").css('display', 'None');
    $(".hoursInfoTable").css('display', 'None');

}
```

But it is not getting in the if block at all in JQuery Mobile.

Comment: simulate mobile use with Chrome, use console and inspect: is the ID present when the event is fired and the 'if' reached?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. When i do console inspect I am getting the error mentioned in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614316/cannot-read-property-getboundingclientrect-of-null-chrome-extension-mkfokfff?noredirect=1#comment47382083_29614316

Comment: Error aside, can you inspect your element IDs?

Comment: All my ids are correct however all i did was instead of using 
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> i used <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"/> N it worked