# Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null chrome-extension://mkfokfffehpeedafpekjeddnmnjhmcmk/toolbar.js:1:13368

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new with JS and current working with JQuery Mobile. I am getting the following error:[image]

I was wondering if its because of the sequence of my scripts placement, i have them as follows:
[image]

I have no idea where and how m i suppose to look for the error. Please  HELP.

Comment: as far as i know you cant mix jquery ui with jqm at the moment. although it may be possible its more hassle than its worth. also in the console log with (chrome-extension..........:13368) line, that's a link to that script, so click on it to take you to the line its failing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this error message is showing when the page first loads. However, if i refresh the page after it loads, it goes. When i click on the link the problem is on Chrome extention: toolbar.js window.setTimeout(function(){x(aw,10)},1000)}break;case"GetElementLocation":aD=aE

Comment: I also tried removing JQuery UI but the error is persistent